# Using macros, how to get unique names for struct fields?

Tags: macros, rust

Suppose I have some macro invoked as such:

```
my_macro!(Blah, (a, b, c));
```

And it outputs something like this:

```
struct Blah {
    a: i32,
    b: i32,
    c: i32
}
impl Blah {
    fn foo() -> i32 {
        a + b + c
    }
}
```

(artificial example)

These fields will be private to the struct, but I need to allow redefinitions. So, the input

```
my_macro!(Blah, (a, b, c, a));
```

Will generate something like:

```
struct Blah {
    a1: i32,
    b: i32,
    c: i32,
    a2: i32
}
impl Blah {
    fn foo() -> i32 {
        a1 + b + c + a2
    }
}
```

The naming scheme doesn't need to follow any logical pattern.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using a compiler plugin, no, I don't believe this is possible.  Two reasons:

1. You can't construct identifiers.  There's `concat_idents!`, but due to the way macros are expanded, it's useless in this situation.
2. You can't do non-literal comparisons.  That is, there's no way of the macro working out that it's already seen `a` once before.

About the closest you could get is to just outright *replace* all the provided identifiers with a fixed list of identifiers, but that's probably not what you want; in that case, it'd be easier to just specify that you want 4 fields, and generate a fixed-size array `[i32; 4]`.

Answer (score 5):

My [**`mashup`**](https://github.com/dtolnay/mashup) crate provides a way for you to expand `my_macro!(Blah, (a, b, c, a))` into fields `x_a`, `xx_b`, `xxx_c`, `xxxx_d` if that naming convention would work for you. We prepend an additional `x` for each field, followed by an underscore, followed by the original field name so that way no fields can end up with conflicting names. This approach works with any Rust version >= 1.15.0.

---

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate mashup;

macro_rules! my_macro {
    ($name:ident, ($($field:ident),*)) => {
        my_macro_helper!($name (x) () $($field)*);
    };
}

macro_rules! my_macro_helper {
    // In the recursive case: append another `x` into our prefix.
    ($name:ident ($($prefix:tt)*) ($($past:tt)*) $next:ident $($rest:ident)*) => {
        my_macro_helper!($name ($($prefix)* x) ($($past)* [$($prefix)* _ $next]) $($rest)*);
    };

    // When there are no fields remaining.
    ($name:ident ($($prefix:tt)*) ($([$($field:tt)*])*)) => {
        // Use mashup to define a substitution macro `m!` that replaces every
        // occurrence of the tokens `"concat" $($field)*` in its input with the
        // resulting concatenated identifier.
        mashup! {
            $(
                m["concat" $($field)*] = $($field)*;
            )*
        }

        // Invoke the substitution macro to build a struct and foo method.
        // This expands to:
        //
        //     pub struct Blah {
        //         x_a: i32,
        //         xx_b: i32,
        //         xxx_c: i32,
        //         xxxx_a: i32,
        //     }
        //
        //     impl Blah {
        //         pub fn foo(&self) -> i32 {
        //             0 + self.x_a + self.xx_b + self.xxx_c + self.xxxx_a
        //         }
        //     }
        m! {
            pub struct $name {
                $(
                    "concat" $($field)*: i32,
                )*
            }

            impl $name {
                pub fn foo(&self) -> i32 {
                    0 $(
                        + self."concat" $($field)*
                    )*
                }
            }
        }
    };
}

my_macro!(Blah, (a, b, c, a));

fn main() {}
```

Answer (score 2):

My [**`paste`**](https://github.com/dtolnay/paste) crate provides a way for you to expand `my_macro!(Blah, (a, b, c, a))` into fields `x_a`, `xx_b`, `xxx_c`, `xxxx_d` if that naming convention would work for you. We prepend an additional `x` for each field, followed by an underscore, followed by the original field name so that way no fields can end up with conflicting names. This approach works with any Rust version >= 1.31.0.

---

```
use paste::paste;

macro_rules! my_macro {
    ($name:ident, ($($field:ident),*)) => {
        my_macro_helper!($name (x) () $($field)*);
    };
}

macro_rules! my_macro_helper {
    // In the recursive case: append another `x` into our prefix.
    ($name:ident ($($prefix:tt)*) ($($past:tt)*) $next:ident $($rest:ident)*) => {
        my_macro_helper!($name ($($prefix)* x) ($($past)* [$($prefix)* _ $next]) $($rest)*);
    };

    // When there are no fields remaining.
    ($name:ident ($($prefix:tt)*) ($([$($field:tt)*])*)) => {
        paste! {
            // Expands to:
            //    pub struct Blah {
            //        x_a: i32,
            //        xx_b: i32,
            //        xxx_c: i32,
            //        xxxx_a: i32,
            //    }
            pub struct $name {
                $(
                    [<$($field)*>]: i32,
                )*
            }

            // Expands to:
            //    impl Blah {
            //        pub fn foo(&self) -> i32 {
            //            0 + self.x_a + self.xx_b + self.xxx_c + self.xxxx_a
            //        }
            //    }
            impl $name {
                pub fn foo(&self) -> i32 {
                    0 $(
                        + self.[<$($field)*>]
                    )*
                }
            }
        }
    };
}

my_macro!(Blah, (a, b, c, a));
```